# Binding function result in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

In C++11 there is a `std::bind` method to connect given rvalue or lvalue references to parameters of a function to pass the given parameters while function invocation e.g.:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int foo(int x, int y) {
   return x + y;
}

int main() {
   std::function<int(void)> f = std::bind(foo, 1, 2);
   std::cout << f() << std::endl;
}
```

My question is, is there a built in method to bind the result of the function to reference of some variable to be able to do something like:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int foo(int x, int y) {
   return x + y;
}

int main() {
   int result;
   std::function<void(int, int)> f = bind_result(foo, result);
   f(1, 2);
   std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: There is no xvalue reference.

Comment: You're right I wanted to say lvalue or rvalue reference in short

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lambda:

```
int result;
auto f = [&result](int a, int b){ result = foo(a, b); };
```

If you want something that forwards arbitrary arguments, you can use a variadic template:

```
auto fvar = [&result](auto... args) {
  result = foo(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
};
```